# Character counting bug when flagging a post

Tags: support, bug, status-declined, flags, character-limit

If you flag a post as 'requires moderator attention', you have to enter a reason of at least 10 characters. Padding out the reason with spaces reduces the number in the "enter at least X characters" visual feedback label, but submitting the reason then (correctly) fails.

The "Please enter at least X" characters count should ignore leading, trailing, or consecutive whitespace characters.

Comment: This is also the same case with comments, it turns out.

Comment: Good point, Grace - that raises the importance of this issue, I believe

Comment: Jeff, can you at least explain why you're declining this?

Comment: This bug still exists one-and-a-half years later ...

Answer (score -2):

This is by design. Don't pad with spaces, and enter a valid comment of the required length.

Comment: I think the OP is agreeing that the system shouldn't permit you to post by adding spaces; his suggestion seems to be that the **indicator** of how many additional characters are needed should also ignore the spaces, so the feedback is aligned with the enforcement.

Comment: Spot on, @Jaydles